# Naming convention of variable name in "ssize_t wb;"

Tags: c, network-programming

I am looking at some socket code.
It declares "wb" as length:

```
ssize_t wb;
wb = sendto(sock, buf, len, 0,
                       (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
```

Does anyone know what "wb" is short for? I thought the variable name should be self-explanatory.

Comment: I'd guess "written bytes".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be "written bytes".

As for variable names being self-explanatory, that's true, but it's in the context of the code.  If you're not using the variable a until hundred lines later, it should probably not require much context.  If you're using it again within a line or two and nobody is going to get confused about it, lots of times it will be shortened to just a character or two.

Comment: Global variables should be given long, descriptive names (`i` and `u` are horrid as global variables).  Short names within a short function, or a short scope within a function, are fine, as you suggest.